# ASP.NET MVC bundles causing errors in W3C HTML validation

Tags: asp.net, w3c-validation, bundles, asp.net-bundling

I do use ASP.NET MVC 5 and I include my JavaScript files with bundles. ASP.NET then generates a file name with a hash value at the end of the file. Between the filename and the hash value is a '=' character. When I validate my HTML code at W3C I get the following error:

> = in an unquoted attribute value. Probable causes: Attributes running together or a URL query string in an unquoted attribute value.

I am not sure if there is an option to fix this error. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this bug?

Comment: can you share some code and output? How you set up the bundle output in your layout page (I'm guessing it's in the layout) or wherever you set it up, and what the output source looks like when inspecting it in your browser dev tools.

Comment: That's how I create my bundles:
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/layout").Include("~/MyScripts/Layout.js"));`
And that's how the source output looks like when inspecting in my browser: 
`<script src=/bundles/layout?v=-29pOi8AKkg3SD9AIodPA0F7mjMTicYAR4SrqO-soDc1 defer></script>`